# Are there any additional missions after completing both campaigns?

Tags: age-of-wonders-3

After completing both Commonwealth and Elven Court campaigns, are there any additional missions? It seems like Merlin and the shadowborn still have a part to play in the story.

I've completed both campaigns on normal and nothing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently the campaign ending marks the ending of the shadowborn/Merlin story. But as you've remarked correctly they're leaving some questions unanswered. Specifically questions regarding:

> Are all Shadowborn accounted for?
>  What is behind the dark gate?

These will probably be used for either an expansion or a 4th installment of the series.

You can still play random maps or scenarios after the campaigns, but as mentioned above, they do not continue the main story.

Comment: Ah, I was worried that would be the answer! Cheers anyways Anzeo!